# How to merge multiple Excel files from a folder and it's sub folders using Python

Tags: python

I have multiple Excel spreedsheets in given folder and it's sub folder. All have same file name string with suffix as date and time. How to merge them all into one single file while making worksheet name and titles as index for appending data frames. Typically there would be small chunks of 200 KB each file of ~100 files in subfolders or 20 MB of ~10 files in subfolders

Comment: Could you let us know what you have tried so far?

Comment: have you tried `pandas.read_excel()`? it returns a dictionary of `sheet_name: DataFrame`.

Comment: I have tried operating using static file name definitions, would be good if it makes consolation by column header from dynamic file list pick, whichever starts with .xls* (xls / xlsx / xlsb / xlsm) and .csv and .txt

import pandas as pd

db = pd.read_excel("/data/Sites/Cluster1 0815.xlsx")

db1 = pd.read_excel("/data/Sites/Cluster2 0815.xlsx")

db2 = read_excel("/data/Sites/Cluster3 0815.xlsx")

sdb = db.append(db1)

sdb = sdb.append(db2)

sdb.to_csv("/data/Sites/sites db.csv", index = False, na_rep = "NA", header=None)

Answer (score 1):

```
This may help you to merge all the xlsx file in current directory.

import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

output = pd.DataFrame()
for file in glob.glob(os.getcwd()+"\\*.xlsx"):
    cn = pd.read_excel(file)
    output = output.append(cn)
output.to_csv(os.getcwd()+"\\outPut.csv", index = False, na_rep = "NA", header=None)
print("Completed +::" )


Note : you need xlrd-1.1.0 library along with pandas to read xlsx files.
```

Comment: Hi Hemadri,

Thanks so much for this, could able to run the code on 4 sample files of 94 MB and the output is seen in CSV with ~1.5 M recors

Comment: The script above is holding good to sort symmetric data frames properly, while the input is arranged in assorted index it Pandas try to push output sorted under zigzag column order, with a warning it would support sort in upcoming release

Answer (score 0):

I have tried operating using static file name definitions, would be good if it makes consolation by column header from dynamic file list pick, whichever starts with .xls* (xls / xlsx / xlsb / xlsm) and .csv and .txt

import pandas as pd

db = pd.read_excel("/data/Sites/Cluster1 0815.xlsx")

db1 = pd.read_excel("/data/Sites/Cluster2 0815.xlsx")

db2 = read_excel("/data/Sites/Cluster3 0815.xlsx")

sdb = db.append(db1)

sdb = sdb.append(db2)

sdb.to_csv("/data/Sites/sites db.csv", index = False, na_rep = "NA", header=None)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic file list merge found to have the below output. However the processing time has to be counted on...

[image: [Merge excel files to CSV 2 million records]

[image: Merge excel files bulk]gur.com/QKTKw.jpg

Answer (score 0):

While running on batch files the code generated below error (please to note that these file are asymmetric in information carried) attached is snap:

[image]